# Add client credentials or from email credentials in PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I set the from in PHPmailer configuration to an email different than the username, and I had this error "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender"

I have the credentials of the from email (port, host, password) but I didn't find how to add these to the configuration in PHP mailer docs.

The properties I need are something similar to this

```
$email->fromHost = "fromHost";
$email->SetFrom("from email");
$email->fromPassword = "password";
$email->fromPort = 465;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the standard options:

```php
$email->Host = 'fromHost';
$email->setFrom('from email');
$email->Username = 'user@example.com';
$email->Password = 'password';
$email->Port = 465;
```

This approach requires that you have access to plain-text credentials of the accounts you want to send from, management of which is outside PHPMailer's scope.

Also note that you can't usually send from arbitrary addresses. It used to work, but nowadays it's usually prevented by DMARC & DKIM settings, and you shouldn't try to spoof email origins anyway.

Comment: The from email I need is different than username. I need username: email1, from: email2. username has its own host, password, port and from has its own host, port, password.

Comment: Well, you're going to be out of luck there. Most email providers do not allow you to send from addresses other than your username, or predefined aliases as it's forgery/spoofing. It makes no sense for the from address to have its own host - you can only send a message from one host at a time.